# Minimum requirements for Unity for Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, minimum-requirements

What are the minimum requirements - android OS version, hardware - to develop android apps with Unity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Android OS 2.0 or later
- Device powered by an ARMv7  (Cortex family)
- CPU GPU support for OpenGLES 2.0 is recommended

See:
http://unity3d.com/unity/system-requirements

Comment: Actually, Unity allows building for ARMv6 with VFP CPU subtypes too, but speed is much lower, and as there is no support for multi-architecture, the same binary also runs suboptimally on ARMv7 devices.

Answer (score 1):

From the [web page](http://unity3d.com/unity/system-requirements):

System Requirements for Unity Authoring 
•Windows: XP SP2 or later; Mac OS X: Intel CPU & "Leopard" 10.5 or later. Note that Unity was not tested on server versions of Windows and OS X. 
•Graphics card with 64 MB of VRAM and pixel shaders or 4 texture units. Any card made in this millennium should work. 
•Using Occlusion Culling requires GPU with Occlusion Query support (some Intel GPUs do not support that). 
•The rest only depends on the complexity of your projects!.

System Requirements for Unity Android Authoring 
• In addition to the general system requirements for Unity Authoring 
• Windows XP SP2 or later; Mac OS 10.5.8 or later 
• Android SDK and Java Development Kit (JDK)